# Ajax producing wrong output in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I can't work out why my ajax is outputting the wrong code. Its outputting loads of css, I believe it's from my 'MySQLDao.php' file but I'm not certain. Code is below.  Someone said it's because the "data: { action : 'getResults' }" line is being ignored, but I'm not sure how to make it so it's not ignored. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Part of my Javascript Code:

```
function callPHP() {
    $.ajax ({
        type: "GET",
        datatype: "application/json",
        url: "MySQLDao.php",
        data: { action : 'getResults' },
        success: function(output) {

            alert(output);

        }

    });

}

callPHP();
```

My PHP file:

```
<?php

    require("Conn.php");

    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    //Class for holding queries
    class MySQLDao
    {
        private $dbhost = null;
        private $dbuser = null;
        private $dbpass = null;
        private $mysqli = null;
        private $dbname = null;
        private $result = null;


        //constructor
        function __construct()
        {
            $this->dbhost = Conn::$dbhost;
            $this->dbuser = Conn::$dbuser;
            $this->dbpass = Conn::$dbpass;
            $this->dbname = Conn::$dbname;
        }

        //Attempt a connection to the database
        public function openConnection()
        {
            //Try and connect to the database
            $this->mysqli = new mysqli($this->dbhost, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpass, $this->dbname);
            //If the connection threw an error, report it
            if (mysqli_connect_errno())
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        //Get method for retrieving the database conection
        public function getConnection()
        {
            return $this->mysqli;
        }

        //Close the connection to the database
        public function closeConnection()
        {
            //If there is a connection to the database then close it
            if ($this->mysqli != null)
                $this->mysqli->close();
        }

        //-----------------------------------QUERY METHODS-------------------------------------

        public function generateRoomID()
        {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO room (room_id) VALUES (null);";
            $result = $this->mysqli->query($sql);
            if ($result == true)
            {
                $toReturn["status"] = true;
                $toReturn["roomID"] = $this->mysqli->insert_id;
                return $toReturn;
            }
            else
            {
                $toReturn["status"] = false;
                $toReturn["message"] = mysql_error($this->mysqli);
                return $toReturn;
            }
        }

        public function saveRoom($data)
        {
            $roomID = $data[0];
            $roomDescription = $data[1];
            $columns = $data[2];
            $rows = $data[3];

            $this->mysqli->autocommit(FALSE);

            $this->mysqli->query("UPDATE room SET room_description='".$roomDescription."' WHERE room_id='".$roomID."';");

            for ($i = 0; $i<count($columns); $i++)
            {
                for ($j = 1; $j<=$rows[$i]; $j++)
                {
                    $currentLabel = "{$columns[$i]}{$j}";
                    $this->mysqli->query("INSERT INTO shelf (shelf_label) VALUES ('".$currentLabel."');");
                    $shelfID = $this->mysqli->insert_id;
                    $this->mysqli->query("INSERT INTO room_shelf (room_id, shelf_id) VALUES ('".$roomID."','".$shelfID."');");
                }
            }

            if ($this->mysqli->commit())
            {
                $toReturn["status"] = true;
                $toReturn["message"] = "Room Created";
                return $toReturn;
            }
            else
            {
                $this->mysqli->rollback();
                $toReturn["status"] = false;
                $toReturn["message"] = "SQL Error";
                return $toReturn;
            }
        }

        public function updateShelf($data)
        {
            $shelfID = $data[0];
            $itemName = $data[1];
        }

        public function getRoomDetails($data)
        {
            $roomID = $data[0];

            $sql = "SELECT room.room_description, shelf.shelf_label, shelf.shelf_id FROM room INNER JOIN room_shelf ON room.room_id=room_shelf.room_id INNER JOIN shelf ON shelf.shelf_id=room_shelf.shelf_id WHERE room.room_id='".$roomID."';";

            $result = $this->mysqli->query($sql);

            if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
            {
                $toReturn["status"] = true;
                $toReturn["message"] = "Room Found";
                $toReturn["room_description"] = $row['room_description'];
                $shelves = [];

                foreach ($result as $row)
                {
                    $currentShelf["shelf_label"] = $row['shelf_label'];
                    $currentShelf["shelf_id"] = $row['shelf_id'];
                    array_push($shelves, $currentShelf);
                }
                $toReturn["shelves"] = $shelves;
                return $toReturn;
            }
            else
            {
                $toReturn["status"] = false;
                $toReturn["title"] = "Error";
                $toReturn["message"] = "Room Not Found";
                return $toReturn;
            }

        }

        public function getResults($data)
        {

            $sql = "SELECT room.room_description FROM room WHERE room.room_id = 1";

            $result = $this->mysqli->query($sql);

            echo json_encode($result);

        }

    }

    $daoObj = new MySQLDao();
    $daoObj->getResults();

?>
```

My Conn Class:

```
<?php
    class Conn
    {
        public static $dbhost = "xxx";
        public static $dbname = "xxx";
        public static $dbuser = "xxx";
        public static $dbpass = "xxx";
    }
?>
```

My BaseClass:

```
<?php
    require("Conn.php");
    require("MySQLDao.php");

    $handle = fopen("php://input", "rb");
    $raw_post_data = '';
    while (!feof($handle)) {
        $raw_post_data .= fread($handle, 8192);
    }
    fclose($handle);

    if (empty($raw_post_data))
    {
        $returnValue["status"] = false;
        $returnValue["title"] = "Error";
        $returnValue["message"] = "No Data Recieved";
        echo json_encode($returnValue);
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        $dao = new MySQLDao();
        if ($dao->openConnection() == false)
        {
            $returnValue["status"] = false;
            $returnValue["title"] = "Error";
            $returnValue["message"] = "Connection Could Not Be Established Between Server And Database";
            echo json_encode($returnValue);
        }
        else
        {
            //Decodes data, dont change
            $body = json_decode($raw_post_data, true);
            $recieved = $body["data"];

            //Gets the result of a query
            //$result = $dao->MySQLDaoMethodName(parameters);

            //Return the result of the query
            echo json_encode($result);
        }
        $dao->closeConnection();
        return;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Do you see the ajax request in your network console at all?  If so, what response code is it getting?  Inspect it to make sure the expected params are being put on it and to see the raw response returned

Comment: So, which of these files is `MySQLDao.php`? It's quite hard to follow the flow if we have no idea what page you're actually calling in your ajax. This code should fail, no matter. You're including `Conn.php` _and_ `MySQLDao.php` while `MySQLDao.php` _also_ includes `Conn.php`. You should get a bunch of errors with this code. Check your servers error log.

Comment: First add:  , error, function(err){console.log(err)} to your ajax call and inspect your console

Comment: In my network console it says something about jquery so I assume thats the ajax? And everything on my network console has the code 200 and either says ok or from memory cache. The first 'PHP' file is the MySQLDao.php file. Also, Where should I add "error, function(err){console.log(err)}"? I've tried putting it within my ajax and I end up getting errors

Comment: no, "jquery" is simply the file containing the jquery library. There's no way you're running the above code without getting errors. At least not "the base class". Please, check your servers error log.

Comment: I literally cannot find any errors. I'm not really using the BaseClass though, I'm just trying to retrieve query results from MySQLDao.php file and put them in my javascript file.

Comment: Dont look at your network tab, select your console tab (the 2nd in chrome) and reload

Comment: Okay, This is what it showed, sorry it's not that spaced out.

jquery-1.7.2.min.js:4 XHR finished loading: GET "http://...MySQLDao.php?action=getResults".
                                                                                                             
           send @ jquery-1.7.2.min.js:4
            ajax @ jquery-1.7.2.min.js:4
             callPHP @ test.html:263
             (anonymous) @ test.html:281

Comment: and if you console.log(output) (instead of alert(output);) ?

Comment: <br />
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-warning' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Warning: Missing argument 1 for MySQLDao::getResults(), called in /home/studb/s2015/cyi15/u5pk/public_html/MySQLDao.php on line 176 and defined in /home/studb/s2015/cyi15/u5pk/public_html/MySQLDao.php on line <i>157</i></th></tr>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>....

Comment: There you have it. getResults expects a parameter. Remove $data from the getResults method (change to public function getResults()) and work from there.

Comment: I was really hoping that would work, and it would make sense if it did. But its still producing that long useless piece of code instead of the query result :( Anymore suggestions? Thanks so much for your help.