# AJAX not producing correct output

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

So I'm trying to call a php method from javascript so I can query a database and get the results into my js functionality. Currently, the `console.log(output)` that is in my ajax is just outputting:

> string '{"action":"getResults"}' (length=23)

Not really sure why it's doing this, it should be returning the query result which is just one entry from the database.

Part of my Javascript file:

```
function callPHP() {
  $.ajax({

    type: "GET",
    datatype: "application/json",
    url: "BaseClass.php",
    data: {
      action: 'getResults'
    },
    //error: function(err){console.log(err)},
    success: function(output) {

      console.log(output);
      //alert(output);
    }
    //error, function(err){console.log(err)}
  });
}

callPHP();
```

BaseClass.php:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

require("Conn.php");
require("MySQLDao.php");

$param=$_REQUEST['action'];

//echo json_encode($_GET);


echo var_dump(json_encode($_GET));

/*
$handle = fopen("php://input", "rb");
$param = '';
while (!feof($handle)) {
    $param .= fread($handle, 8192);
}
fclose($handle);
*/

if (empty($param))
{
    $returnValue["status"] = false;
    $returnValue["title"] = "Error";
    $returnValue["message"] = "No Data Recieved paige" .$param ."...";
    echo json_encode($returnValue);
    return;
}
else
{
    $dao = new MySQLDao();
    if ($dao->openConnection() == false)
    {
        $returnValue["status"] = false;
        $returnValue["title"] = "Error";
        $returnValue["message"] = "Connection Could Not Be Established Between Server And Database";
        echo json_encode($returnValue);
    }
    else
    {
        //Decodes data, dont change
        $body = json_decode($param, true);
        $recieved = $body["data"];

        //Gets the result of a query
        //$result = $dao->MySQLDaoMethodName(parameters);

        //Return the result of the query
        //echo json_encode($result);
    }
    $dao->closeConnection();
    return;
}
?>
```

Conn.php - this is all the connection info, * out for confidential reasons:

```
<?php

    error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    class Conn
    {
        public static $dbhost = "***";
        public static $dbname = "***";
        public static $dbuser = "***";
        public static $dbpass = "***";
    }
?>
```

MySQLDao.php - this file holds the querys:

```
   <?php

    error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    //Class for holding queries
    class MySQLDao
    {
        var $dbhost = null;
        var $dbuser = null;
        var $dbpass = null;
        var $mysqli = null;
        var $dbname = null;
        var $result = null;


        //constructor
        function __construct()
        {
            $this->dbhost = Conn::$dbhost;
            $this->dbuser = Conn::$dbuser;
            $this->dbpass = Conn::$dbpass;
            $this->dbname = Conn::$dbname;
        }

        //Attempt a connection to the database
        public function openConnection()
        {   

            //Try and connect to the database
            $this->mysqli = new mysqli($this->dbhost, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpass, $this->dbname);
            //If the connection threw an error, report it
            if (mysqli_connect_errno())
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        //Get method for retrieving the database conection
        public function getConnection()
        {
            return $this->mysqli;
        }

        //Close the connection to the database
        public function closeConnection()
        {
            //If there is a connection to the database then close it
            if ($this->mysqli != null)
                $this->mysqli->close();
        }

        //-----------------------------------QUERY METHODS-------------------------------------

        public function getResults($data)
        {



            $sql = "SELECT room.room_description FROM room WHERE room.room_id = 1";

            $result = $this->mysqli->query($sql);


            //if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {
            //  $obj = mysql_fetch_object($result, 'obResults');

            //}

            //echo json_encode($result);

            echo($result);

            //return "yay";

        }

    }
?>
```

How to fix this and simply just print out the query result to the webpage ? I've been stuck on this for ages. Any help is welcome and appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to rename the question. This isn't about calling a PHP function - it's about an AJAX call producing output that isn't what you expect.

Comment: Well, you never actually echo out of your final `else` block. So if `$param` isn't empty, and `$dao->openConnection()` is truthy, nothing is sent back.

Comment: `//if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {
            //  $obj = mysql_fetch_object($result, 'obResults');` - I'm wondering if you're trying to use those `mysql_` functions where they don't intermix with the `mysqli_` api.

Comment: And how is this different to your query here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45722685/ajax-producing-wrong-output-in-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ajax producing wrong output in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45722685/ajax-producing-wrong-output-in-javascript)

Comment: The output is different

Answer (score 1):

> Not really sure why it's doing this

It's doing that because of this:

> ```
> echo var_dump(json_encode($_GET));
> ```

You take the results of parsing the query string, turn it to a string of JSON, then pass that string through `var_dump` (which tells you it is a string, what the string is, and how long it is).

> it should be returning the query result which is just one entry from the database

The relevant section of PHP is this:

> ```
>    $body = json_decode($param, true);
>    $recieved = $body["data"];
> ```

You try to parse `$param` as JSON (which fails, because `getResults` is not valid JSON). You then try to read the `data` property from it (which fails, because it never had one).

If you want to make a database query, then you need to actually query the database.

If you want some output at that point, then you need to supply some output.

---

Aside:

> ```
> datatype: "application/json",
> ```

- The property is called `dataType` not `datatype`
- It accepts the value `"json"`, not `"application/json"`
- The PHP currently returns plain text (although it has a `text/html` content type because you haven't overridden it) which can't be parsed as JSON

Comment: I hope you don't mind the edit. See the comment about it inside. Edit: Not my downvote here, no idea why you got that.

Comment: @Fred-ii- — That sounds like something better proposed as a stylesheet change for quotes. The `>` already marks it as quoted material.

Comment: Ok sorry. I've the habit of using quotes when quoting someone, which to me makes sense: *"To be or not to be..."* - William Shakespeare ;-) Edit: See my comment to Quentin ;-) @BenM

Comment: @Fred-ii- I agree with Quentin, the quoted material doesn't require emphasis (SO uses `<em>`, not `<i>`).

Answer (score 1):

Your BaseClass only outputs if you have an error because you never use echo

```
if (empty($param))
{
    $returnValue["status"] = false;
    $returnValue["title"] = "Error";
    $returnValue["message"] = "No Data Recieved paige" .$param ."...";
    echo json_encode($returnValue);//Only output
    return;
}
else
{
    $dao = new MySQLDao();
    if ($dao->openConnection() == false)
    {
        $returnValue["status"] = false;
        $returnValue["title"] = "Error";
        $returnValue["message"] = "Connection Could Not Be Established Between Server And Database";
        echo json_encode($returnValue);//Only output
    }
    else
    {
        //Decodes data, dont change
        $body = json_decode($param, true);
        $recieved = $body["data"];

        //Gets the result of a query
        //$result = $dao->MySQLDaoMethodName(parameters);

        //Return the result of the query
        //echo json_encode($result);
        //All of these are commented out
        echo json_encode($result);//Fix
    }
    $dao->closeConnection();
    return;
}
```

Comment: I've uncommented these, so now it's //Decodes data, dont change
   $body = json_decode($param, true);
   $recieved = $body["data"];
   
   //Gets the result of a query
   $result = $dao->getResults($recieved);
   
   //Return the result of the query
   echo json_encode("the result" .$result);

However its still not producing what I want

Comment: what is the output after the change?

Comment: string '{"action":"getResults"}' (length=23)
{"current_field":null,"field_count":null,"lengths":null,"num_rows":null,"type":null}"the result"

Answer (score -2):

Make sure you set the `Content-type` header before you echo *anything* on the page:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
```

That way the client knows to expect JSON.

Comment: Since the PHP isn't outputting JSON, telling the browser to expect JSON would be counterproductive at this stage.

Comment: Only if `if (empty($param))` is true, which it isn't

Comment: (or if `$dao->openConnection()` returns false)